# Does maven dependencies get added to class path?

Tags: maven, jar, classpath

I have two independent projects A and B both are being built using maven. Project B is more of a resources project. I am using maven to package jar for this project.

**Now for project A, i add project B's jar as the dependency. How i will be able to access resource files from project B's jar in side some java file in project A.**

I have confirmed that jar for Project B is being installed in Maven's local repository.

I searched alot but none of the answers seem to help.

Following is the directory structure for

src
|_
  main
  |_
    resources
    |_
      dir1
      |_
        dir2
        |_
          dir3
          |_
            Some_config_file.txt

I want to access this Some_config_file.txt from Project A, how can i find the path relative to classpath

Any help / suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all files from `src/main/resources` are part of the final JAR and they are in the same path as classes. In other words your `_Some_config_file.txt` will land up next to `_dir1._dir2._dir3.Foo.class` compiled class.

All such items are placed on flat CLASSPATH, i.e. contents of each JAR share the same namespace on the CLASSPATH. In order to read such file, you need to using `ClassLoader`:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/_dir1/_dir2/_dir3/_Some_config_file.txt`);
```

Comment: Which class's class loader i will be using though ? the jar file in context above is just being used to package all the resources and a dummy hello world class.

Comment: @MadEyeMoody85: If you are lucky, use *any* `ClassLoader` (any class). In more complex environments (with class loader hierarchies) you might have to think for a while which class was loaded by the same `ClassLoader`.

Comment: I tried InputStream resourceStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/some-file-name.txt"); and its returning null.